# Cisco ASA 5506: Adding two public IP's that are on the same subnet for the primary and backup interface

Tags: cisco, routing, ip, cisco-asa

Im programming a Cisco ASA 5506. I need to add a primary (public) IP that is x.x.x.82/24 and a backup IP that is x.x.x.81/24. The ASA wont allow me to do this as it gives me an error: "the IP address cannot overlap with the subnet of interface outside" when i go to add the backup (public) IP. Is there a reason i cannot do this, and is there a workaround for that?

Im wondering if a possible workaround could be to make the subnet mask for the primary 255.255.255.254 since that contains the .82 - .83 IP's, and make the subnet for the backup 255.255.255.252 since that contains .80 - .83

My naivety may be overlooking something here though. any help is appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish specifically with that configuration? There's likely an alternative.

Comment: @boomi So i believe the site im configuring it for has a fiber router and DSL modem from the same ISP. I want to configure the outside interface(port 1) to use the fiber router, but should something happen to the fiber, i want it to swing over to the backup interface(port 8) on the DSL modem. but since they are on the same subnet, i cant even add the IP address to the backup interface

Comment: Are you sure they have the same addressing? That's very odd that 2 separate circuits would be provisioned with the same address space, especially given that they're different types of connections, even though they may be through the same provider.  Are you sure none of the octets are different?

Comment: @JesseP. actually, upon further investigation, it seems one is a 100/100 ethernet over fiber circuit and i believe the other is just a 25/25 ethernet... im guessing they are sharing the same router in this case?

Comment: It's possible they're just separate handoffs since they may not have known if you needed fiber or copper and just provided both.

Comment: Even if they're coming from the same ISP device, I'd expect them to be addressed differently too. Can you double check with the provider? You won't be able to assign addresses in the same subnet to separate layer 3 interfaces on the 5506. You can however look into redundant interfaces https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa97/configuration/general/asa-97-general-config/interface-echannel.html#ID-2077-000000af

Comment: You technically probably could change the subnet mask as you mentioned but that's a really bad way to work around the issue.  I'd suggest that you have the ISP either split up the subnet and create a second gateway on their device for you to use with your secondary uplink or get a completely different block of addresses. A lot of the time, you'd have a separate /30 block just for peering and then they just route through that so you aren't wasting addresses in your main scope. So, you could get 2 /30 blocks and then use weights to prefer one path over the other.

Comment: And use NAT as needed for your real scope.

Comment: This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now.
It's not feasible to configure same public address ip range subnet mask on two interfàce of devices "overlapping error can be triggered" if it is outside interfàce or any other interface of ASA firewall . Please recheck onces again with both ISPs how come both internet service providers are using same public ip pool subnet it seems to be abnormal and not possible in real time world both ISPs never use same public ip range subnet .

Reverify with both ISP with there provided interface ip and pool assigned for your network